# PrintWriter overwrites each word or doesn't overwrite whole file

Tags: java, printwriter

I have a problem regarding PrintWriter class. I am trying to write a long text in a file. At first, I had the overwriting problem. Each time I run it, just last word is seen there. Then, I added FileWriter but, this time it doesn't overwrite the file whenever I run it again.

```
private static void storyTeller(String wordsToWrite) throws IOException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(wordsToWrite);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outFile, true));
    String temp;

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        temp = scan.next();
            if (counter == 0) {
                out.print(temp);
                System.out.print(temp);
            }
            counter = counter + temp.length() + 1;
            if (counter > 80) {
                System.out.println();
                out.println();
                System.out.print(temp);
                out.print(temp);
                counter = temp.length() + 1;
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(" " + temp);
                out.print(" " + temp);
            }

    }
    scan.close();
    out.close();
}
```

If I don't add FileWriter parameter to PrintWriter, in outFile there is only one word (the last word). If I add 'new FileWriter(outFile, true)' like the code above, this time it doesn't overwrite when I run program again.

This one is what I get with FileWriter, but I need to overwrite each time I run the program

[image: This one is what I get with FileWriter, but I need to overwrite each time I run the program]

This is what I get when I delete FileWriter for overwriting

[image: This is what I get when I delete FileWriter for overwriting]

Thanks.

Comment: Change the second argument to the FileWriter constructor to false (it is append).

Comment: Hi Elliot. Thanks for answer. This time it writes only the last word. Like the photo below. What I need is to write in a file as if writing at console using System.out.print() method.

Comment: So, what is the problem? What do you want it to do?

Comment: I want to overwrite the file each time I run the program. But, it overwrites each word or it doesn't overwrite anything.

Comment: please mention data for  `wordsToWrite`  input?

Comment: Something tells me that you are calling this method once for each word in your real text. Care to add more code to the question, that shows exactly when and with what data the method is called? And where `counter` is defined?

Comment: Yea.... I exactly do it. I call this method for each word. I think I can handle it now. 'counter' is defined as field. Thanks a lot. I couldn't see it.

Comment: If you write it like this, you get the first word of the text written twice. It's because of the wrong conditions. First you test _counter == 0_ later in _else_ you test _counter <= 80_

Comment: To solve this you just need to write *else if* instead of the first *if*. That means *else if (counter > 80)*.
However I would go the way EJP suggested in his answer below. That is the right approach, not the one you've chosen.

Comment: @WrongRhyme. I changed is as EJP says. But I wrote 'counter != 0' at first if.

Comment: Yes, that's right. One more potential troublemaker can be the condition *if (counter > 80)*. I would suggest to use *if (counter >= 80)* instead, because if counter would be 80, the loop would read another word from Scanner and you would go over 80 chars. Also the condition for testing the length 80 chars should be before you print the word into PrintWriter (and screen).

Comment: I agree. I took it above and I added this if (counter + temp.length() > 80)

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out how to solve the problem. I delete the file each time I start the program. And, I use this line as shown above.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outFile, true));'
```

In case I don't delete the file, the program doesn't overwrite the file. Instead, it goes on writing the new text at the end of the written file.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a real meal of this. Don't bother to accumulate the string in memory, just write the words as you get them:

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    temp = scan.next();
    if (counter == 0) {
        out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(" ");
        counter++;
    }
    out.print(temp);
    System.out.print(temp);
    counter = counter + temp.length();
    if (counter > 80) {
        System.out.println();
        out.println();
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually, this is an assignment and there are requirements such as no space after last word of each line. So, I added the blanks in front of each word and for the first word there is no space before. Also, using this doesn't change the overwriting problem. I think it is difficult to explain the problem. I need to overwrite this file each time I run the program. But, I can't. If I change the second argument to the FileWriter constructor to false, then it writes only the last word of all.

Comment: Thank you. I wrote this code but, I changed first if as counter != 0.